# my WordPress website is adding the domain URL to the end of each permalink,

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting, permalinks

I'm currently facing an issue with my WordPress website where the domain URL is being appended to the end of each permalink. This results in broken links and a poor user experience. I'm seeking assistance to resolve this problem.

Here's an example of the issue I'm facing:

On my website, the URLs are structured as follows:
https://example.com/product-tag/pce-428-class-2-data-logging-spl-me-price/www.example.com

As you can see, the domain URL ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) is erroneously added to the end of the permalink, causing the link to break.
how can i fix this issue?

Checked permalink settings: I have verified that the permalink settings in WordPress are correctly configured. I'm using the "Post name" structure.
Examined plugins: I disabled all plugins to check if any of them were causing the problem. However, even with all plugins deactivated, the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your WordPress admin dashboard.
Navigate to "Settings" and click on "Permalinks".
Check the "Custom Structure" field under "Common Settings".
Make sure that the custom structure does not include the domain URL. It should typically be set to something like /%postname%/.
If you see the domain URL included in the custom structure (e.g., http://example.com/%postname%/), remove it so that only the permalink structure remains.

Answer (score 0):

If after checking on settings>permalinks clear, you can try change to default theme to make sure it's not from custom code